# How store image in dll file and use it in wpf?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I need to store image in dll file and use it in wpf
instead of use local path like that 
`<Image Height="128" Width="95" Margin="21,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Source="C:\Users\PC\Desktop\MyCar.png" Stretch="Uniform"/>`

Comment: You mean you need a resource?  Add the image to your project and set its "Build Action" to "Resource".  Then you can refer to it with a relative path

Comment: Thank you very much , it's working and sorry for dumb question .

Comment: do you mean embed the image into the DLL so that when the DLL is distributed the image goes with the image and you do not need to distribute the image as a separate file?

Comment: @jeff yes, that I meant.